# Express view engine not recognizing data sent to front end

Tags: mysql, node.js, pug

I am making a website and I am trying to set up a review option. I query the reviews from my Mysql DB and res.send the data to the ".pug" file. The data does not show. However it does show if I put type out the data manually. such as

```
{review: "this is a review"}
```

this works just fine but when I try to access the data directly it does not.

```
var review;   
app.get('/', function(req,res) {
con.query("SELECT * FROM reviews.eatingReviews", function(err, rows) {
    review = rows[0].Review;
    console.log(review)
    if (err) throw err;
});
res.render('test',
    {review: review});
```

pug file

```
   extends layout
   block content
      p= review
```

Data

```
 RowDataPacket {
 Name: 'James Laskey',
 Email: 'james.laskey23@gmail.com',
 Review: 'This book is classic!',
 Rating: 5 }
```

I need to get this information to be recognized by the html. It keeps showing as undefined. I tried JSON.parse on the object and that did not work either. Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The view is empty because `res.render` is executed before `con.query` finish fetching your data from database. `con.query` is a async function.

As workaround, you must put `res.render` inside `con.query`:

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM reviews.eatingReviews", function(err, rows) {
    review = rows[0].Review;
    console.log(review)
    if (err) throw err;

    res.render('test',
      {review: review});
});
```

Comment: Omg I've been searching for hours for a solution! Thank you this worked!